# Javascript not being loaded only in custom taxonomy template

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, templates, wp-enqueue-script

I have a taxonomy called `categorias_de_receita` in my plugin and a custom template for displaying this taxonomy posts. I don't know why Javascript files are not being loaded **only** in this specific template.

There are no errors, no 404, etc. It is like `wp_enqueue_script` is not being called **only** in this specific template (other pages are working fine).

**Here's the function:**

```
// Enqueue Scripts
function la_enqueue_scripts() {

//Styles are being loaded
wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'css/slick.css', array(), 'all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-theme', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'css/theme/slick-theme.css', array(), 'all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css");
wp_enqueue_style( 'la-receitas', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'css/la-receitas.css' , array(), 'all');

// Not being loaded
wp_enqueue_script('slick', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'js/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('mixitup', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'js/mixitup.min.js', array(), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('mixitup-pagination', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'js/mixitup-pagination.min.js', array(), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('la-receitas', LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC . 'js/la-receitas.js', array(), null, true);

} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'la_enqueue_scripts');`
```

`LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC` constant:

```
if ( !defined('LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC')){
    define('LA_RECEITAS_PUBLIC', plugins_url('/la-receitas/public/', _FILE_ ));
}
```

Comment: Are they not being loaded, or are they just not working? Can you see the script tags on the page?

Comment: I checked for it too... there are no script tags on the page.

Comment: Does the template have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in it?

Comment: Yes, i am using `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in the start/end of the template.